# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my SQL Query

```
DECLARE @Amount int
SELECT @Amount = COALESCE(@Amount+ ', ', '') + Amount FROM Hotel
```

while executing this query I am getting error as :

```
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int"
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to cast the number to string explicitly as otherwise it will try to do an implicit cast from string to number.

Also declare the variable to be the correct datatype...

```
 DECLARE @Amount varchar(max)
 SELECT @Amount = COALESCE(@Amount+ ', ', '') + CAST(Amount AS VARCHAR(11))
 FROM Hotel
```

You might also want to look at [`XML PATH`](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) for this as you are on 2008.